# d3.js Bar Chart transitions not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a simple bar chart here that should nicely transition all the bars over slightly to the left to make room for a new bar to appear on the right of the graph whenever new data is submitted via a button click event, however they all seem to fire over to the left side on top of each other.

Here is my code for my transition:

```
bars.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return x(i);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.count);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.count);
        });
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/foL2Lcg1/1/

The test data for entry on the button submission I'm using is 'Service: blah' and 'Count: 60000' which you can enter below the graph.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you looked at this: https://bl.ocks.org/RandomEtc/cff3610e7dd47bef2d01

Comment: Thanks for the link! It helped out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example here : https://bl.ocks.org/RandomEtc/cff3610e7dd47bef2d01

I have created this fiddle with your data : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/foL2Lcg1/5/

I have added a draw function which you pass data. So instead of rewriting code as you were, you start by calling this function, and once you add/remove some data, you call this function again with the new set of data and it updates. Here is the function :

```
function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.service; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select('.x.axis').transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.count);
        })
   .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.count);
        })



  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.service); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}
```

Now update as you were on button click :

```
d3.select("button")
      .attr("id", "submit")
      .on("click", function() {

          var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
          var count = document.getElementById("count").value;

          var json = {
            "count": count,
            "service": service
          };

          data.push(json);
          draw(data)
          })
```

Here is working code if fiddle isn't working :

```js
var data = [

      {
        service: "QA",
        count: "25262"
      }, {
        service: "QB",
        count: "42386"
      }, {
        service: "QUERY_NOTICICATIONS",
        count: "14042"
      }, {
        service: "TTL",
        count: "4088"
      }

    ];



// Mike Bostock "margin conventions"
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight/1.5 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// D3 scales = just math
// x is a function that transforms from "domain" (data) into "range" (usual pixels)
// domain gets set after the data loads
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

// D3 Axis - renders a d3 scale in SVG
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    //.ticks(10, "%");

// create an SVG element (appended to body)
// set size
// add a "g" element (think "group")
// annoying d3 gotcha - the 'svg' variable here is a 'g' element
// the final line sets the transform on <g>, not on <svg>
var svg = d3.select(".chart") 
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("text") // just for the title (ticks are automatic)
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") // rotate the text!
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

// d3.tsv is a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest, returns array of arrays (?) for a TSV file
// type function transforms strings to numbers, dates, etc.
 draw(data);

function type(d) {
  // + coerces to a Number from a String (or anything)
  d.count = +d.count;
  return d;
}
 

function draw(data) {
  // measure the domain (for x, unique letters) (for y [0,maxFrequency])
  // now the scales are finished and usable
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.service; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  // another g element, this time to move the origin to the bottom of the svg element
  // someSelection.call(thing) is roughly equivalent to thing(someSelection[i])
  //   for everything in the selection\
  // the end result is g populated with text and lines!
  svg.select('.x.axis').transition().duration(300).call(xAxis);

  // same for yAxis but with more transform and a title
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(300).call(yAxis)

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL WORK!
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data) // (data) is an array/iterable thing, second argument is an ID generator function

  bars.exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(300)
    .attr("y", y(0))
    .attr("height", height - y(0))
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
    .remove();

  // data that needs DOM = enter() (a set/selection, not an event!)
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.count);
        })
   .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.count);
        })
    
       

  // the "UPDATE" set:
  bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.service); }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); }); // flip the height, because y's domain is bottom up, but SVG renders top down

}


d3.select("button")
      .attr("id", "submit")
      .on("click", function() {
        
          var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
          var count = document.getElementById("count").value;

          var json = {
            "count": count,
            "service": service
          };

          data.push(json);
          draw(data)
          })
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

svg text {
  pointer-events: none;
}

rect {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg class="chart"></svg>

  <div class="input">
    <p>Service :
      <input id="service" type="text"></input> Count :
      <input id="count" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Tooltip</strong></p>
    <p><span id="service"></span></p>
    <p><span id="count"></span></p>
  </div> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a small mistake in your code. Use `x(d.service)` instead of `x(i)` to calculate x position of bars in click function.

```
 bars.transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return x(d.service); //instead of x(i);
         })
         .attr("y", function(d) {
           return y(d.count);
         })
         .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
         .attr("height", function(d) {
           return height - y(d.count);
         });
```

```js
var data = [

     {
       service: "QA",
       count: "25262"
     }, {
       service: "QB",
       count: "42386"
     }, {
       service: "QUERY_NOTICICATIONS",
       count: "14042"
     }, {
       service: "TTL",
       count: "4088"
     }

   ];

   var width = 960,
     barHeight = 500;

   var margin = {
       top: 20,
       right: 30,
       bottom: 50,
       left: 60
     },
     width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

   var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([height, 0]);

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(x)
     .orient("bottom");

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(y)
     .orient("left");

   var chart = d3.select(".chart")
     .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



   x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
     return d.service;
   }));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
     return d.count
   })]);


   chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);

   chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Count");

   chart.selectAll(".bar")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("x", function(d) {
       return x(d.service);
     })
     .attr("y", function(d) {
       return y(d.count);
     })
     .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height - y(d.count);
     })
     .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
       var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
       var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;

       //update tooltip positiom
       d3.select("#tooltip")
         .style("left", xPos + "px")
         .style("top", yPos + "px")
         .select("#service")
         .text("Service: " + d.service);

       d3.select("#tooltip")
         .style("left", xPos + "px")
         .style("top", yPos + "px")
         .select("#count")
         .text("Count: " + d.count);

       //show tooltip
       d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

     })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
       d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
     });






   d3.select("button")
     .attr("id", "submit")
     .on("click", function() {


       var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
       var count = document.getElementById("count").value;

       var json = {
         "count": count,
         "service": service
       };

       data.push(json);
       console.log(data);

       x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
         return d.service;
       }));
       y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
         return d.count
       })]);

       chart.select(".x.axis")
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .call(xAxis);

       chart.select(".y.axis")
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .call(yAxis);

       var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
         .data(data);

       bars.enter().append("rect");


       bars.attr("class", "bar")
         .attr("x", function(d) {
           return x(d.service);
         })
         .attr("y", function(d) {
           return y(d.count);
         })
         .attr("height", function(d) {
           return height - y(d.count);
         })
         .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
         .on("mouseover", function(d) {
           var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
           var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;

           //update tooltip positiom
           d3.select("#tooltip")
             .style("left", xPos + "px")
             .style("top", yPos + "px")
             .select("#service")
             .text("Service: " + d.service);

           d3.select("#tooltip")
             .style("left", xPos + "px")
             .style("top", yPos + "px")
             .select("#count")
             .text("Count: " + d.count);

           //show tooltip
           d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

         })
         .on("mouseout", function() {
           d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
         });

       bars.transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return x(d.service);
         })
         .attr("y", function(d) {
           return y(d.count);
         })
         .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
         .attr("height", function(d) {
           return height - y(d.count);
         });








     })
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}
#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.chart text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
svg text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
rect {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
rect:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart"></svg>

<div class="input">
  <p>Service :
    <input id="service" type="text" />Count :
    <input id="count" type="text" />
  </p>
  <br/>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  <p><strong>Tooltip</strong>
  </p>
  <p><span id="service"></span>
  </p>
  <p><span id="count"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than mine, as it showed you what was wrong in your code :) I would recommend implementing a draw function though so your code isn't duplicated etc (OP)

Comment: Thanks You. Good suggestion.